# Web API get time of request via action filter attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, actionfilterattribute

I was wondering if it was possible to get the time of a request via a `custom action filter attribute`? I have the following:

```
public sealed class FooFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        if (actionExecutedContext.Response != null)
        {
            var start = actionExecutedContext.Request.Headers.Date; //this is null
            var end = actionExecutedContext.Response.Headers.Date;                
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know the total time it took to process the request however, I can't seem to get access to the `DateTime` value of when the request was initiated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of `OnActionExecuted` I don't think that value is known to the framework anymore.  But you can get it in `OnActionExecuting` and store it in the request.  Something like this:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    actionContext.Request.Properties.Add(this.GetType().FullName, Stopwatch.StartNew());

    base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
}
```

Now you can get *that* value at the end of the action:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
{
    Stopwatch stopWatch = null;
    if (actionExecutedContext.Request.Properties.ContainsKey(this.GetType().FullName))
        stopWatch = actionExecutedContext.Request.Properties[this.GetType().FullName] as Stopwatch;
    if (stopWatch != null)
    {
        var elapsedTime = stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        // do something with that value
    }

    base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
}
```

Comment: That's great thanks you. However, seems a little dirty. Using the DelegatingHandler approach is it the same as in adding to the properties collection?